# How to create another column in a data frame based on repeated observations in another column?

Tags: r, case

So basically I have a data frame that looks like this:

| BX | BY |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 1 | 12 |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 14 |
| 2 | 14 |
| 3 | 5 |

I want to create another colum `ID`, which will have the same number for the same values in `BX` and `BY`. So the table would look like this then:

| BX | BY | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 1 |
| 1 | 12 | 1 |
| 1 | 12 | 1 |
| 2 | 14 | 2 |
| 2 | 14 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 | 3 |

Comment: Or `cumsum(!duplicated(df1[c("BX", "BY")]))`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R way.
Subset the data.frame by the grouping columns, find the duplicated rows and use a standard `cumsum` trick.

```r
df1<-'BX    BY
1   12
1   12
1   12
2   14
2   14
3   5'
df1 <- read.table(textConnection(df1), header = TRUE)

cumsum(!duplicated(df1[c("BX", "BY")]))
#> [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3

df1$ID <- cumsum(!duplicated(df1[c("BX", "BY")]))
df1
#>   BX BY ID
#> 1  1 12  1
#> 2  1 12  1
#> 3  1 12  1
#> 4  2 14  2
#> 5  2 14  2
#> 6  3  5  3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: At first it seemed like it worked but it did not. The `ID`column I get has repeated observations like I wanted but not the right ones. If `BX`and `BY`have both the same values in two different rows, I want those two rows to have the same `ID`.

Comment: @starski In the code above, all rows have the same `ID` for the same values of `BX` and `BY`, the output matches your expected output. Is it failing with your real data set? If yes, can you post a reproducible example of it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
transform(dat, ID = as.numeric(interaction(dat, drop = TRUE, lex.order = TRUE)))

  BX BY ID
1  1 12  1
2  1 12  1
3  1 12  1
4  2 14  2
5  2 14  2
6  3  5  3
```

Or if you prefer `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(across()) %>%
  mutate(ID = cur_group_id()) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 × 3
     BX    BY    ID
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     1    12     1
2     1    12     1
3     1    12     1
4     2    14     2
5     2    14     2
6     3     5     3
```