# How to create a column based on repeated values in other columns?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

| BX | BY |
| --- | --- |
| 4.1 | 12.4 |
| 4.1 | 12.4 |
| 4.1 | 12.4 |
| 10.0 | 14.5 |
| 10.0 | 14.5 |
| 9.7 | 5.6 |

The `BX` and `BY` variables are coordinates. I want to create an `ID` column with values to group points with the same x and y coordinates. It should like this:

| BX | BY | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 12 | 1 |
| 4 | 12 | 1 |
| 4 | 12 | 1 |
| 10 | 14 | 2 |
| 10 | 14 | 2 |
| 9 | 5 | 3 |

Comment: How does this differ from the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74041363/how-to-create-another-column-in-a-data-frame-based-on-repeated-observations-in-a) you asked yesterday?

Answer (score 2):

With dplyr...

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 |> 
  group_by(BX, BY) |> 
  mutate(ID = cur_group_id())
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#> # Groups:   BX, BY [3]
#>      BX    BY    ID
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     4    12     1
#> 2     4    12     1
#> 3     4    12     1
#> 4    10    14     3
#> 5    10    14     3
#> 6     9     5     2
```

data

```
df1 <- structure(list(BX = c(4, 4, 4, 10, 10, 9), 
                      BY = c(12, 12, 12,14, 14, 5)), 
                 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this ended up working finally!

Comment: Pleased to read that the answer works: please consider accepting [Accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, id := .GRP, by = .(bx, by)]
setDF(df)
```